# What the book means for "percentage difference"?

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy

From Atkins-De Paula, Physical Chemistry, Ninth Edition, page 485

[image]

Not sure what the books means as "percentage difference".
Btw, this is my attempt

Fundamental vibration, in wavenumber, generic formula:

$\varepsilon_{\nu=1}-\varepsilon_{\nu=0} = \bar{\omega}$

$\bar{\omega} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi c} \sqrt{\dfrac{k}{\mu}}$

$\text{let }1) \ce{^{23}Na}\ce{^{35}Cl} \,\,\, \mathrm{and} \,\,\, 2) \ce{^{23}Na}\ce{^{37}Cl}$

$\mu_1 = 2.31 \times 10^{-26} \, \mathrm{kg}$

$\mu_2 = 2.37 \times 10^{-26} \, \mathrm{kg}$

$\text{percentage difference} = 100 - \dfrac{\omega_2}{\omega_1} = 100 - \dfrac{\sqrt{1/\mu_2}}{\sqrt{1/\mu_1}}$

According to what is reported in the book, the solution is 1.089 percent. Is this procedure right?

Comment: Percentage difference is the ordinary relative difference, just expressed in percentage. The only problem is what to take as the reference 100%? Value A, value B or their average ?  // BTW if both omegas are the same the percentage difference is hardly 99% as it is 0%.

Comment: 4 is by 20% smaller (percentage difference) than 5. 5 is by 25% bigger than 4. They are respectively (100/9)%  smaller/bigger than 4.5 as the average of 4 and 5.

Comment: I formatted the text as you requested. Now, is my reasoning right?

Comment: Read again the second part of my second comment.

Comment: By the last equation line you say -- by other words -- that 5 is by 99% bigger/smaller than 5. That is not true, is it?

Comment: So, is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: Is 5 by 99% bigger than 5?

Comment: as @Poutnik has pointed out it is actually the *relative* difference that is meant in the question. This has to be a ratio as you realise,  but of the difference in $\omega$ because you do not know $k$  it has to cancel out. Make this then multiply by 100.

Answer (score 2):

The relative percentage difference (RPD) of $b$ with respect to $a$, where the value $a$ is given or taken as the reference 100% value(typically if $b$ is deviation from $a$), is:

$$\text{RPD} = \frac{b-a}{a} \cdot 100 \%.$$

In your case:

$$\text{RPD} = \frac{\bar{\omega}_
2-\bar{\omega}_
1}{\bar{\omega}_
1} \cdot 100 \%.$$

In case the reference 100% value is not given, is unclear, or is explicitly said so, as the reference can be taken the arithmetic average of both values(typically if both have equal, parallel status). Then:

$$\text{RPD} = \frac{2(b-a)}{a+b} \cdot 100 \%$$

In your case:

$$\text{RPD} = \frac{2(\bar{\omega}_
2-\bar{\omega}_
1)}{\bar{\omega}_
1+\bar{\omega}_
2} \cdot 100 \%.$$

---

Regarding how exactly it was meant by the book, I just refer to one of my canned comments:

**A** asking **B** *"What does **C** mean by **X**?"* may not provide a satisfactory nor reliable answer. **A** should ask **C**.

The hint can be which of 3 possible options for the reference fits the given result the best.